# Why is my for loop duplicating my values?

Tags: javascript

I have a function to find the combination of 3 unique points.

In other languages, such as java, the same code works fine.

However, in javascript, it duplicates the amount of output.

```js
function findCombinations(lines) {
  let count = 0;
  let points = [];
  let res = [];
  for (let line of lines) {
    let pointArray = (line).split('');
    for (let c of pointArray) {
      points.push(c);
    }
  }
  points.sort();
  points.reverse();
  points = points.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
  });
  console.log("Unique points " + points);

  for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 2; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < points.length - 1; j++) {
      for (let k = j + 1; k < points.length; k++) {
        let combination = points[i] + points[j] + points[k];

        let p1 = false;
        let p2 = false;
        let p3 = false;

        for (let line of lines) {

          if (line.includes(points[i]) && line.includes(points[j]) && !line.includes(points[k])) {
            p1 = true;
          }

          if (line.includes(points[i]) && line.includes(points[k]) && !line.includes(points[j])) {
            p2 = true;
          }

          if (line.includes(points[j]) && line.includes(points[k]) && !line.includes(points[i])) {
            p3 = true;
          }

          if (p1 && p2 && p3) {
            count++;
            res.push(combination);
            console.log('Found it: ' + count + ' Combination: ' + combination);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  console.log("Total Triangles: " + res.length + ' ' + res);
}

findCombinations(["AKLM", "BDNOPQR", "EWVUTS", "21IZ", "CJ",
  "ABC", "KNWF2", "LPUXH1", "MRSYZJ",
  "ADEFGHIJ", "MQTXG2C", "KOVXY"
])
```

The only way that I found to clear out the duplications is to filter the resulting array with:

```
  res = res.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
  });
```

I don't like that, I would like to know why it's duplicating and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
          if (p1 && p2 && p3) {
            count++;
            res.push(combination);
            console.log('Found it: ' + count + ' Combination: ' + combination);
          }
```

should not be inside the `for (let line of lines)` loop. You're pushing the combination and incrementing the counter for each line that matches, instead of once if there are any matches.

```js
function findCombinations(lines) {
  let count = 0;
  let points = [];
  let res = [];
  for (let line of lines) {
    let pointArray = (line).split('');
    for (let c of pointArray) {
      points.push(c);
    }
  }
  points.sort();
  points.reverse();
  points = points.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
  });
  console.log("Unique points " + points);

  for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 2; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < points.length - 1; j++) {
      for (let k = j + 1; k < points.length; k++) {
        let combination = points[i] + points[j] + points[k];

        let p1 = false;
        let p2 = false;
        let p3 = false;

        for (let line of lines) {

          if (line.includes(points[i]) && line.includes(points[j]) && !line.includes(points[k])) {
            p1 = true;
          }

          if (line.includes(points[i]) && line.includes(points[k]) && !line.includes(points[j])) {
            p2 = true;
          }

          if (line.includes(points[j]) && line.includes(points[k]) && !line.includes(points[i])) {
            p3 = true;
          }

        }
        if (p1 && p2 && p3) {
          count++;
          res.push(combination);
          console.log('Found it: ' + count + ' Combination: ' + combination);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  console.log("Total Triangles: " + res.length + ' ' + res);
}

findCombinations(["AKLM", "BDNOPQR", "EWVUTS", "21IZ", "CJ",
  "ABC", "KNWF2", "LPUXH1", "MRSYZJ",
  "ADEFGHIJ", "MQTXG2C", "KOVXY"
])
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (p1 && p2 && p3)` is more times true. So you get all combinations in your result.